# JSON model class: full or a part

Tags: android, json

I have not found answer in Google and stackoverflow, so I am here.

**Should I create FULL model class for JSON, when I am working with Retrofit?**

For example, server returning big JSON, and it model class (http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) this is almost 3000 raws of code but I need only few elements from this JSON.

May be I should create full model only in certain situations?

### UPD:

and jsonschema2pojo creates even several classes.

Comment: What do you mean by Full model ? Only  A class containing all properties should be created .  3000 Rows means 3000 instances of this class .

Comment: No, you don't need full model class if you want to use partial data from JSON response. Just create a class with entities which are needed.

Comment: @ADM I mean I have a JSON and it type - array of object, so this structure is like: [{}], [{}]... and inside this structure I am also have [] and {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is depend on the situation you can create only that part of json which you want to in your app and leave that part that you don't want on your code. Spouse if you have 3000 objects in json and if you need only 500 objects from that json you can create on that 500 objects in your code you dont need to create all the 3000 objects in your code.

Comment: So it depends you are saying. I have a JSON and it type - array of object, so this structure is like: [{}], [{}]... and inside this structure I am also have [] and {}. in this situation should I create the full model?

Comment: "jsonschema2pojo creates even several classes."

Comment: yes you have to create the full model in case if you need any object from that array class

Comment: according to that json format if you don't need to bar class then you should not create Bar class in your project